# View Assembly from DMD with line numbers

Tags: d, dmd

How can I look at the assembly code for a specific line in the source code?

I tried compiling my source with DMD and `-g` and `-gc` (on Windows) and used `objconv` to output the assembly of the `.obj` and `.exe`, but there don't seem to be any hints about the line numbers etc.
But when I use `Code::Blocks` and set a breakpoint it shows some assembly like this

```
004030CE    // C:\...\TEST\main.d:291   matrix.array[3] = 0;
004030CE    mov dword [ebp+0xfffffec4], 0x0
```

so there must be some information about the lines somewhere...

Comment: The information is probably in a debugging format that `objconv` doesn't understand. If `objconv` supports PDB files, you could try passing the executable through `cv2pdb`. You may also want to take a look at the DigitalMars `dumpobj` utility.

Comment: thanks, I don't think, that `objconv` understands pdb, and I also couldn't get `cv2pdb` running even after copying the dlls form VS into the cv2pdb folder or adding them to the `PATH`. I think I'll create a C::B project over my current Project, and use breakpoints for getting the assembly... (breakpoints are not hit with Ddbg, when I add src files as external files)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use http://d.godbolt.org/ (gdc only).

Comment: That's not going to work very well for anything but trivial pieces of code... in which case you probably don't care about line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful and simple way is in Visual Studio / [Visual D](http://www.dsource.org/projects/visuald) plugin.

Simply place a breakpoint, start program in debug mode, and display Disassembly from menu Debug/View.

If you don't have Visual Studio you can download Visual Studio Shell (empty IDE) into which you can install the VisualD plugin. [VS Shell 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=115) or [VS Shell 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30663)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can ceate a CodeBlocks (v10.05) project over an existing project to use `DMD` with the `Ddbg_gdb` debugger and view the assebly at breakpoints:

1. `File>New>Project...>D application`
2. Set the project name as you like
3. change the "Folder to create Project in" to the directory in which you already have your source files
4. change the "Resulting file name" to the directory from (3) and add the "Project filename". (if your project folder is `C:\some\path\srcBaseDir` and your project filename is `myProject.cbp` then the resulting file should be `C:\some\srcBaseDir\myProject.cbp`)
5. set the "Digital Mars D Compiler" & Finish
6. `Settings>Compiler and Debugger...`

   - set all the directories you need for the "Digital Mars D Compiler"
   - change the Toolchain `executables>Debugger` to "ddbg_gdb"
   - click OK
7. Right-click on your project and Add Files recursively and add all your source files you need

Now, you should be able to set breakpoints, which will be correctly recognized by Ddbg_gdb and view the assembly with the Disassembly view in `Debug>Debugging Windows>Disassembly`